# IntelliJ IDEA format methods and constructors different

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

We would like to format constructors different from methods.

A method should not have a new line after '(' while a constructor should have a new line after '('.

For example:

```
public class ThisIsASampleClass {

    @Inject
    public ThisIsASampleClass(
            FirstClass firstClass,
            SecondClass secondClass){
    } 

    public void foo1(int i1, int i2){
    }
}
```

We need this, because it is easier to merge the constructors like this.

Is this possible?

*Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any specific setup for Code style pertaining only to constructors, only methods in general (Settings - Editor - Code Style - Java - Wrapping and Braces).

Create a task with Jetbrains, maybe they'll add it.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: I did allready know that there is no direct method for this. That is the reason i'm asking if this could be achived in any way. But still, you are right, i created a issue on youtrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166851

Comment: Oh i did just see that the issue tracker has 880050 issues and mostly they never get answered in years. So this issue tracker seems to be a dead end.